# Searchkit track change on searchbox input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search-box, searchkit

I'm trying to track an onChange event on a [SearchBox](http://docs.searchkit.co/v0.6.2/docs/components/basics/search-box.html) component from the library [Searchkit](http://www.searchkit.co/). I want to make some kind of autocomplete-popup, below the input field.

I'm having a Searchbar component and a SearchbarPopup component. When I type something inside the Searchbox input I want the  to show or hide when input is empty. But for now I'm fine with getting a response from the console.log.

```
export class Searchbar extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
  }
  onChange(){
    console.log('input has changed!')
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <SearchkitProvider searchkit={searchkit}>
        <Layout>
          <div className="search">
            <div className="search_query">
              <SearchBox
                autofocus={true}
                searchOnChange={true}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                prefixQueryFields={[
                  "Author",
                  "Title"
                ]}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </Layout>
      </SearchkitProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<div id="cb_Zoekbalk">
    <div class="sk-layout">
        <div class="search">
            <div class="search_query">
                <div class="sk-search-box">
                    <form>
                        <div class="sk-search-box__icon"></div>
                        <input type="text" data-qa="query" class="sk-search-box__text" placeholder="Waar ben je naar op zoek?" value="">
                        <input type="submit" value="search" class="sk-search-box__action" data-qa="submit">
                        <div data-qa="loader" class="sk-search-box__loader sk-spinning-loader is-hidden"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my project, I'm also needed to set a listener on SearchBox query change. Here is what place I've found where you can get a response:

```
searchkit.setQueryProcessor((plainQueryObject) => {
  console.log('input has changed!')

  return plainQueryObject
})
```

Link to a [documentation for SearchkitManager](http://docs.searchkit.co/v0.7.0/docs/core/SearchkitManager)